# Updating a Kivy label from ardunio temperature sensor data

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I know there's a few other kivy/label update threads here, but after a few days of applying the guidance from these, I'm still no closer to getting a label in kivy to update with temperature data, from an ardunio. This is for a campervan control panel, which should control actuators to fold out the sofa bed on button presses, and display sensor data on a screen.

I have the serial port connection working, as the actuator control buttons work, but I'm struggling to get a label to update with temp sensor data. The ardunio IDE serial monitor shows that the ardunio is outputting the temperature okay, and if I copy/paste the temp_sensor function into a new script, it prints the data okay.

I'm new to programming, python, and kivy, so apologies if I'm being dumb!

Here's the python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

import serial
import webbrowser
import time

browser_launch = 'https://www.google.com'
ser= serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', 9600, timeout=5) 


class MainWindow(Screen): #The home screen, that navigates to other control windows, and has the buttons controlling the actuators.

    desktop = ObjectProperty(None)
    settings = ObjectProperty(None)
    bed = ObjectProperty(None)
    sofa = ObjectProperty(None)

    def desktop_button(self):
        webbrowser.open_new(browser_launch)
        print("Desktop Pressed")

    def settings_button(self):
        print("Settings Pressed")

    def bed_button(self):
        ser.write(b'B')  #These buttons work, and interact with the ardunio as they should.
        print("Bed Pressed")

    def sofa_button(self):
        ser.write(b'S')
        print("Sofa Pressed")

    pass

class TempWindow(Screen): #Second screen that is navigated to from the main screen. This will display temperature inside the van, (and outside, plus control the heater eventually)

    temp_sensor_inside = NumericProperty(0)

    def temp_sensor(self):  #If I run this function in a seperate python script it works.
        time.sleep(2)
        while 1:
            temp_reading = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
            float_temp = float(temp_reading)
            return float_temp
    pass

class DataWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()

    ser.close()
```

And the corresponding part of the .kv file:

```
<TempWindow>:
    name: 'temp'

    temp_sensor_inside: temp_sensor_inside

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'background.png'

        Label:
            id: temp_sensor_inside
            text: str(root.temp_sensor())
            font_size: 50
            pos_hint: {'x': -0.15, 'y': 0.1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example (based on your code) that should help you. In the example below, I have left out a few things that do not affect the answer. And I have replaced your code to access the temperature sensor with just a global variable named `float_temp`, since I don't have such a sensor:

```
import threading
import time
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

float_temp = 55.0


class TempWindow(Screen): #Second screen that is navigated to from the main screen. This will display temperature inside the van, (and outside, plus control the heater eventually)

    temp_sensor_inside = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        # start polling the temperature
        threading.Thread(target=self.poll_sensor).start()


    def poll_sensor(self):
        global float_temp
        while 1:
            # temp_reading = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
            # float_temp = float(temp_reading)
            float_temp += 1.5
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.set_temp, float_temp))
            time.sleep(2)

    def set_temp(self, temp, dt):
        self.temp_sensor_inside.text = str(temp)

kv_str = '''
<TempWindow>:
    temp_sensor_inside: temp_sensor_inside
    name: 'temp'
    Label:
        id: temp_sensor_inside
        text: '000'
'''

class TempWindowApp(App):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string(kv_str)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(TempWindow())
        return sm


TempWindowApp().run()
```

The `on_enter()` method is executed when the `TempWindow` is displayed. That method starts a new thread to monitor the temperature sensor, because you don't want to tie up your GUI with a loop that runs forever. The `poll_sensor()` method gets the current temperature from your sensor (in my case, it just increments `float_temp`) and calls `set_temp()` using `Clock.schedule_once()`. The `Clock.schedule_once()` runs the `set_temp()` back on the main thread (required for code that modifies the GUI), and the `set_temp()` changes the text of the `Label` through the `ObjectProperty` that references the `id` from the `kv`.